# Error message on website when I did a test run of the "like" button

Tags: web, facebook-like

I added the "like" button to my website, www.nivinlaw.com.  I did a "test run," and got an error message that the page failed to provide a valid list of admins.  I am listed as the sole admin on my company's Facebook page.

What do I do to stop giving this error to people who "like" my page?  Thanks.

Comment: I had a similar problem. Remove the 'link' tag (iframe) and save your page, then add the iframe script again and try.

Answer (score 1):

You have to place some `og` meta tags on your page... There is an `og:admins` tag that you can use...
`<meta property="fb:admins" content="USER_ID"/>` 
Here is some information about using the open graph protocol with facebook.

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraph/